# Router issue. (Huawei WS319)

Tags: windows, networking, router

When I plug in cable from router to PC the Huawei Official website pops up.

How is it possible over connecting ethernet cable to make my browser open?

How to switch it off?

P.S. Site opens up by itself only when internet is connected.

P.P.S. So with a custom firmware someone can make a fishing site pops up automatically when plugging a cable, strange options.

How to prevent automatic browser opening when plugging in a cable?

Answer (score 2):

1. You connect the cable
2. Windows tries to connect to the internet
3. Router puts in a HTTP redirect to huawei website
4. Windows gets a webpage response and opens a browser to handle it

Its a similar procedure for captive portals(hotels, trains, free wifi networks) where you automatically get a page to login.